# Why won't my Objective C modules see my Swift 3 classes in Xcode 8?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, xcode8

I've been struggling with this for months now. I've found many answers, but so far none have worked for me.

I have a working iOS app that has been in the store for several years. It was originally written in objective C and then I added some Swift code to leverage features of the language. When I converted the project to Xcode 8 and Swift 3, it created over 500 errors that that I had to slowly weed out. Eventually I got down to just one class of error; Swift classes are not visible to objective C modules.

Now… I have declared the with @objc, and I even made sure that the classes were declared as public, just in case. These things should have mattered anyway, as the swift classes are derived from NSObject.

Here's a cutdown example;

```
@interface PDAppDelegate ()

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) PDGameManager *gameManager;

@end


@implementation PDAppDelegate {
    NSString * stoppedMusicKey;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [PDAward resetTutorial];
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc class PDAward: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var awardValue: Int16

    enum AwardType: Int16 {
        case Start = 0, Spin = 1, Water = 2, Treats = 3, Food = 4, Album = 5, Facebook = 101, Ball = 102, Name = 103, Gesture = 201, Weekly = 301, Stop = -1
    }

    var award: AwardType {
        get {
            return AwardType(rawValue: awardValue)!
        }
        set {
            awardValue = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    @objc class func resetTutorial() {
        // reset stuff
    }
}
```

Of course, this is heavily cut down, but I hope I've captured all the elements of the problem.

Let me emphasise that I had this code working before. Why doesn't it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope I've captured all the elements of the problem

You haven't. The most important thing is the thing you've omitted: the Objective-C code must import the Swift header:

```
#import "MyModuleName-Swift.h"
```

Comment: Note, however, that if your Swift code for any reason does not compile, there won't be a Swift header and you'll get an error on the `#import` statement above. In other words, your Swift problems must be _completely_ ironed out before Objective-C can see _any_ Swift material.

Comment: I had included the header, but for some reason there was already a file called PD-Swift.h in the file system that was not in the project. That file was being found in the search for the header files, and preventing the generated header file from being found. This was causing the swift classes to be invisible, but also making the cause of the problem invisible as well. Deleted the false header file, and it all compiled.

Your solution wasn't quite on the mark, but given the info I provided it was close enough to rate an "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a header file, for your Objective-C and Swift code to work together. And you also must import all your .h OBJ-C files into it.

Here is some more info to help you out. http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. You guys set me on the right path.